# Replacing non-zero values while leaving na's as is

Tags: r, tidyr, dplyr

The data look like:

```
structure(list(group = c(1, 1, 1, 1), month = c(5, 6, 7, 8), 
    newcomers = c(1, 2, 0, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), codepage = 65001L)
```

I'm trying to:

1. Change non-zero values of 'newcomers' to '1'
2. Leave zero of 'newcomers' as '0'
3. Leave na's as na's

... while keeping other columns intact.

I tried using mutate_at; I wanted to ask for your advice regarding how to leave na's as is.

In the end, the data would look like:

```
+-------+-------+-----------+------------+
| group | month | newcomers | newcomers2 |
+-------+-------+-----------+------------+
|   1   |   5   |     1     |      1     |
+-------+-------+-----------+------------+
|   1   |   6   |     2     |      1     |
+-------+-------+-----------+------------+
|   1   |   7   |     0     |      0     |
+-------+-------+-----------+------------+
|   1   |   8   |     na    |     na     |
+-------+-------+-----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the column to logical and coerce it to binary

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
       mutate(newcomers2 = +(as.logical(newcomers)))
```

-output

```
#    group month newcomers newcomers2
#1     1     5         1          1
#2     1     6         2          1
#3     1     7         0          0
#4     1     8        NA         NA
```

Or create an expression

```
df1 %>%
     mutate(newcomers2 = +(newcomers > 0))
```